# ¿Como puedo indicar que cierto parámetro no es obligatorio pasarlo?

Tags: c#

Tengo un método que recibe 3 parámetros pero al momento de usarlo en la aplicación que estoy construyendo solo le necesito pasar 2 parámetros. Ejemplo.

Método:

```
public static void MiMetodo(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    // Código
}
```

Call Método (1):

```
MiMetodo(param1, param2);
```

*En esta llamada solo uso param1 y param2*

Call Metodo (2):

```
MiMetodo(param2, param3);
```

*En esta llamada solo uso param2 y param3*

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Aunque se puede solucionar con parametros opcionales y mandar los parametros con nombre, no me cierra del todo el uso, podrias especificar porque una misma funcion puede recibir los parametros de esa forma, y sobre todo que son todos del mismo tipo? como sabria la funcion si mando los parametros 2 y 3 o 1 y 3 o 1 y 2? mas alla de los nombres me refiero

Comment: nada, por eso las etiquetas quedan eliminadas :D

Comment: Te planteo el problema en si. Pasa que tengo un método para crear una `cookie` la cual recibe 3 parámetros tal como lo indique anteriormente, recibe A, B y C. Este método necesito llamarlo 2 veces en mi controlador para crear 2 `cookie` la primera a crear es con el valor de A y la segunda a crear es con el valor de B. El parámetro C seria el nombre de la `cookie`

Comment: entonces no recibe tres parametros.. recibe 2 siempre. el nombre de la cookie, y otro con el valor a guardar.. donde estaria el tercer parametro?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, estaba implementando mal los parámetros. Ya que A y B seria un valor X debería ser un solo parámetro, por ende como dices el tercer parámetro no existiría. Gracias por tu observación, creo que estaba bloqueado que no me percate antes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tienes dos opciones

1.- Sobrecargar el metodo, osea crear dos metodos con el mismo nombre pero diferentes parametros:

```
 public void metodo(string param1,string param2, string param3)
 {} 
 public void metodo(string param1,string param2) 
 {}
```

2.- Crear parametros opcionales dandole valores predeterminados a los parametros

esto lo logras cuando en la declaracion del metodo le das un valor

```
 public void metodo(string param1,string param2, string param3="50")
 {

 }
```

param1 y param2 son obligatorios, pero param3 no por que ya tiene un valor,
entonces la llamada quedaria asi :

```
 metodo("hola","mundo")
```

Si utilizas varios parametros opcionales, tendras que indicar en la llamada del metodo a cual parametro opcional le estas mandando valor

```
 public void metodo(string param1="20",string param2="50")
 {

 }
 metodo( param1 : "10" , param2 : "20" );
```

Nota: los parametros opcionales deben ser los ultimos parametros en declararse, esto debido a que al ser "opcionales" el compilador no puede determinar si lo estas incluyendo o no en medio de dos parametros obligatorios.

Comment: solo como detalle, seria raro que el tipo de parametro fuera un string, pero le pasaras numeros (y sobre todo que el valor por defecto fuera un numero ;) ). aparte de eso, tienes mi +1

Comment: woops, Gracias por la observacion !

Comment: Igual pensaba en hacer una sobrecarga del método creo que seria los mas viable... pero creo haber visto en algunos ejemplos por Internet que se le agregaban el signo `?` antes del `string` o antes del nombre del parámetro. En realidad no me acuerdo en que parte iba y no logro dar con ese ejemplo.

Comment: @vcasas ? es para que un valor pueda valer null. los strings ya son nullables, con lo cual no necesitas agregarlo.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por esa observación, de todas formas creo que recargar el método quizás es la mas indicada pero ahí cada uno puede elegir de que forma cree correcto hacerlo (por la respuesta de mas abajo).

Comment: @vcasas El simbolo `?` se utiliza para validar si un objeto es nulo antes de utilizar alguna de sus propiedades o asignarlo a otro objeto. Va después del nombre del objeto y antes del método. Solo se ejecutara si dicho valor no es `null`. No sirve para antes de la asignacion porque nulo no asigna valores. Por ejemplo: `param1.toString();` `toString()` te marcara error si `param1` es `null`. Sin embargo `param1?.toString();` aqui `toString();` no se ejecutara si `param1` es `null`.

Comment: Genial esa explicacion ! Y esa validacion `param1?` se puede hacer aca `public static void MiMetodo(string param1, string param2, string param3)` ?. Por que lo intente pero me da un error de sintaxis.

Comment: @vcasas no. Debes hacerlo dentro del metodo, no en los parámetros. Si intentas hacer eso al recibir un parámetro, estas definiendo el tipo de un objeto nullable y no todos lo soportan. Por ejemplo un parametro `long` solo asigna números, no se puede asignar a `null` porque es de tipo primitivo. Sin embargo en `C#` se implementa la interfaz `nullable` y al marcarlo como `long?` puede asignarse a `null`. No tiene nada que ver con utilizar los parámetros en el método ya que al recibirlo especificas un tipo. Mientras que cuando lo utilizas en el método evaluas una condición. Necesitas un ejemplo?

Comment: @Andrespengineer Si, seria ideal si me puedes indicar con un ejemplo.

Comment: @vcasas copia el código que esta en [este link](https://codeshare.io/2KBeZ8), pegalo y ejecutalo en un compilador de `C#`. Si no tienes uno, pruebalo en [este compilador online](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-c-sharp-online), te comente los ejemplos para que entiendas como funciona cada cosa. Buena suerte.

Comment: Excelente ! muchas gracias @Andrespengineer

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos opciones, hacer una **sobrecarga de metodos** que llamen a tu método principal, para  esto tendrias que crear tantos metodos como casos quieras o enviar los parametros de manera predeterminada. Por ejemplo:

```
public static void MiMetodo(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    // Tu codigo
}

public static void MiMetodo(string param1, string param2) 
{
   MiMetodo(param1, param2, null);
}

public static void MiMetodo(string param1, string param3) 
{
   MiMetodo(param1, null, param3);
}

public static void MiMetodo(string param1) 
{
   MiMetodo(param1, null, null);
}
```

**Otra alternativa (parametros definidos):**

```
public static void MiMetodo(string param1 = null, string param2 = null, string param3 = null)
{
    // Tu codigo
}
```

Ten en cuenta que en todos los casos debes hacer las respectivas validaciones de  nulo de cada parámetro enviado. En el método principal que es donde recibe los 3 parámetros.

La ventaja sobre parametros definidos, es que no tienes que crear demasiados metodos para llamar al principal, ya que si solo quieres enviar `param2` y `param3` tienes que crear un metodo que reciba dichos parametros e invocar al principal utilizando `param1` como null. Como te dije, parametros opcionales es mejor con pocos parametros, pero puedes optar por la primera opción si vas a crear todos los casos.

Comment: Aunque no lo creas, las librerias de MS usan la primera version. Parece mas incomodo, pero de esa forma no tenes una logica terrible (sobre todo si son muchos parametros) en un solo metodo, que tendria que validar parametro por parametro y saber que hacer con cada uno de ellos si no vino. en general el metodo que no tiene parametros opcionales ya sabe que hacer con cada uno si viene null o no (o los otros metodos que lo llaman se lo pueden resolver antes)

Comment: @gbianchi Así es, incluso Java que no trabaja con parametros opcionales funciona así. Sin embargo esto se torna conflictivo cuando es un método que recibe muchos parámetros y todos son opcionales. Para todo caso hay que saber como manejar la lógica y saber dividir los métodos. Por lo general yo utilizo parámetro opcionales cuando son uno o dos.

Comment: a mi nunca me ha gustado utilizar parametros opcionales,  aunque admito que simplifican tu codigo.

Comment: Creo que no seria escalable esta solución a futuro, lo veo mas como un parche.

Comment: @vcasas Si necesita enviar todos los parámetros opcionales tiene esas dos alternativas. Otra alternativa que puede hacer es definir un arreglo de parametros y establecer el keyword params en los parametros que va a recibir en el metodo. El problema es que no es mantenible ya que solo se guiaran por indices los parametros y tendras que hacer muchas validaciones. La razon por la que te puse el ejemplo de crear metodos que llamen al principal es para evitar codigo repetitivo y manejarlos todos desde uno. Pero puedes utilizar la segunda alternativa.

Comment: @vcasas como que escalable? que es realmente lo que queres hacer? esta solucion y la otra son totalmente correctas.

Comment: @vcasas Creo que la pregunta aquí es: ¿Cuál es tu definición de "escalable"?

Comment: Mucho depende de porqué necesitas distintos parámetros. Por ejemplo, si los parámetros son mutuamente exclusivos, por ejemplo, si tienes un constructor que recibe una cadena de conexión (un string) y otro donde recibes la ip del servidor, la base de datos a conectarse, etc. lo ideal ahí es usar sobrecarga de métodos, pero si tienes un método donde uno o mas parámetros no te interesan (pueden ser nulos), sería crear código de más el hacer sobrecarga y lo mejor sería usar parámetros opcionales, ya que el compilador rellenaría el parámetro faltante con el valor default.